# gulp+browser-sync не обновляет html

Tags: gulp, browsersync

Хотя в консоли пишет Reloading Browser

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  jade = require('gulp-jade'),
  browserSync = require('browser-sync');


gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.sass')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }));
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'app'
    },
    notify: false
  });
});

gulp.task('jade', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/jade/**/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'sass'], function() {
  gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.sass', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('app/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);

});
```

Comment: Возможно не правильно объявлена переменная `browserSync = require('browser-sync');` должно быть `browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();`

Answer (score 1):

Вы держите исходники с конвертированными файлами вместе? Жуть.

Вам в комментарии ответили, что нужно вызывать create() при require browser-sync. Попробуйте сделать, хотя я уверен, что ситуацию не изменит.
У вас ситуация когда вы сделали изменения в jade файле, а браузер вроде бы обновился, но ничего не поменялось? А jade файлов уже много, хотя в начале таких проблем с обновлением браузера не было? Если так, то вам нужно поставить [gulp-changed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-changed).
Jade, pug из коробки не умеет делать кэширование, из-за чего каждый раз при изменение одного файла начинают обрабатываться все файлы Для этого нужен gulp-changed, чтоб он сравнивал файлы которые выплевывает jade с файлами которые уже есть и пропускал дальше, только те которые изменились.

Такая беда происходит, потому, что галп сообщает browser-sync о перезагрузки, а jade еще не выплюнул все файлы и browser-sync вроде бы обновился, но изменения не те подхватил.

Так же советую добавить [gulp-jade-inheritance](https://github.com/juanfran/gulp-jade-inheritance), для кэширования самого jade.

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: "app"
    },
    port: 8080,
    open: true,
    notify: false
  });
});
```

Comment: попробуй прописать порт. Мне помогло